# Как сделать жадную выборку в Spring data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Есть 2 сущьности `User` и `Role`. Мне нужно сделать выборку `User` что бы `Role` которая у `User` на полях тоже инициализировалась.

Что то вроде `Hibernate.initialize(User.getRole())`.

Или жадной выборки :

`from User u join fetch u.role where u.username := username and u.password := password` и как-то сделать `.setParameter()`.

Но так как я использую интерфейс `CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>` то мне надо использовать характерный для Spring Data подход.

Испробовал уже много вариантов не буду захламлять ими вопрос. Но если в 2-х словах все упирается в валидность синтаксиса `Query()` аннотации для метода:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Query("...?...")
    User findDistinctFirstByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста это решить, наверняка Spring data позволяет это делать, возможно нужно выбрать другой интерфейс или как-то хитро построить запрос..? Спасибо.

Вот мои сущьности:

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
    private List<Role> role;

    ...get & set & constr...
}

@Entity(name = "user_roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    ...get & set & constr...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id       SERIAL      NOT NULL,
  username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  enabled  BOOLEAN     NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_role_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  role         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (username, role),
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)
);
```

Comment: Я так понимаю в случае с Spring Data указание FetchType ничего не решает?

Comment: @iksuy не знаком с FetchType посмотрю что за зверь спасибо.

Comment: В аннотациях вида `@SomeToSome` как параметр указывается, для Hibernate он по умолчанию `LAZY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам необходимо иногда выбирать жадно, а иногда лениво, и поэтому не подходит указание типа выборки в аннотации `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, то можно попробовать воспользоваться [стратегией загрузки графа](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph):

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.detail", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("role"))
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
    private List<Role> role;
    ...
}

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    @EntityGraph(value = "User.detail", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    User findDistinctFirstByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

Comment: упал с `WARN: HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
авг 16, 2017 12:55:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
авг 16, 2017 12:55:12 PM` `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying и org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

Comment: я добавил sql схемы возможно путаница с первичными ключами? У меня в users `PRIMARY KEY (username)` а в классе User `@Id` стоит над полем id возможно это понимается как первичный ключь и это несоответствие и вызывает осключение?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас типы полей внешнего ключа отличаются, в одной таблицы `integer`, а в другой `character varying`. Но к текущему вопросу это не относится.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)` username в обои таблицах VARCHAR(20) или вы под внешним ключем что-то другое имели в виду?

Comment: Не я, Hibernate.